# Expected input to torch Embedding layer with pre_trained vectors from gensim

Tags: vector, pytorch, gensim, word2vec, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to use pre-trained embeddings in my neural network architecture. The pre-trained embeddings are trained by gensim. I found [this informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802495/1150683) which indicates that we can load pre_trained models like so:

```
import gensim
from torch import nn

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('path/to/file')
weights = torch.FloatTensor(model.vectors)
emb = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(torch.FloatTensor(weights.vectors))
```

This seems to work correctly, also on 1.0.1. My question is, that I don't quite understand what I have to feed into such a layer to utilise it. Can I just feed the tokens (segmented sentence)? Do I need a mapping, for instance token-to-index?

I found that you can access a token's vector simply by something like

```
print(weights['the'])
# [-1.1206588e+00  1.1578362e+00  2.8765252e-01 -1.1759659e+00 ... ]
```

What does that mean for an RNN architecture? Can we simply load in the tokens of the batch sequences? For instance:

```
for seq_batch, y in batch_loader():
    # seq_batch is a batch of sequences (tokenized sentences)
    # e.g. [['i', 'like', 'cookies'],['it', 'is', 'raining'],['who', 'are', 'you']]
    output, hidden = model(seq_batch, hidden)
```

This does not seem to work so I am assuming you need to convert the tokens to its index in the final word2vec model. Is that true? I found that you can get the indices of words by using the word2vec model's `vocab`:

```
weights.vocab['world'].index
# 147
```

So as an input to an Embedding layer, should I provide a tensor of `int` for a sequence of sentences that consist of a sequence of words? Example use with dummy dataloader (cf. example above) and dummy RNN welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Embedding) says the following

> This module is often used to store word embeddings and retrieve them using indices. The input to the module is a list of indices, and the output is the corresponding word embeddings.

So if you want to feed in a sentence, you give a `LongTensor of` indices, each corresponding to a word in the vocabulary, which the `nn.Embedding` layer will map into word vectors going forward.

Here's an illustration

```py
test_voc = ["ok", "great", "test"]
# The word vectors for "ok", "great" and "test"
# are at indices, 0, 1 and 2, respectively.

my_embedding = torch.rand(3, 50)
e = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(my_embedding)

# LongTensor of indicies corresponds to a sentence,
# reshaped to (1, 3) because batch size is 1
my_sentence = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1]).view(1, -1)

res = e(my_sentence)
print(res.shape)
# => torch.Size([1, 3, 50])
# 1 is the batch dimension, and there's three vectors of length 50 each
```

In terms of RNNs, next you can feed that tensor into your RNN module, e.g

```py
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=50, hidden_size=5, batch_first=True)
output, h = lstm(res)
print(output.shape)
# => torch.Size([1, 3, 5])
```

I also recommend you look into [torchtext](https://github.com/pytorch/text). It can automatate some of the stuff you will have to do manually otherwise.