# Building dictionary with GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin returns ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pytorch, gensim

When trying to load  `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` with pytorch `Vector` [struct](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vocab.html#vectors) I am getting

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'\x00\x00\x94:\x00\x00k\xba\x00\x00\x

I have tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710537/pytorch-gensim-how-to-load-pre-trained-word-embeddings) (@robodasha) but without success. My goal is to build a vocabulary with the loaded embedding using `build_vocab` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved with the following way using `gensim`.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from torchtext import data
import gensim

emb_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(emb_bin_filename, binary=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1", unicode_errors='ignore')
word2index = {token: token_index for token_index, token in enumerate(emb_model.index2word)}
TEXT = data.Field(tokenize=my_tokenizer(), lower=lower)
TEXT.build_vocab(train_data)
TEXT.vocab.set_vectors(word2index, torch.from_numpy(emb_model.vectors).float().to(device), emb_model.vector_size)
```